# How to Execute a Stored Procedure in Oracle 11g

Tags: database, oracle, procedure, execution

Hi I'm spending a lot of time searching for execution of stored procedures in Oracle 11g. If anyone can share the answer that will be so helpful.

Regards,
Pranay.

Comment: Hi @pranay, welcome to stackoverflow.  We do have a similar question which I would recommend that you look at here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860935/execute-a-stored-procedure-in-oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working if I press `F5` but it's working if I highlight the Execute Statement and right click and press Run the Script Option. I got help from my Colleague AK.

Eg:

```
Var result1 refcursor;
EXECUTE Schemaname.Tablename (param1,param2,:result1);
print result1
```

Regards,
Pranay.

Answer (score 2):

You call it with `execute`:

```
EXECUTE my_procedure ('arg1', 'arg2');
```

Comment: ...only if you do that in SQL*Plus

Comment: It's not working I got one input parameter and one ouput cursor declared as parameters. I'm passing the i/p param but do I need to pass o/p param as well, If I need to how can I do it.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, and I found lot of posts without answers. This is solution:

```
begin
your_procedure;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your cursor is a ref cursor:

```
declare
  lcsr sys_refcursor;
begin
  package.procedure(input => input_parameter_value, output => lcsr);

   /* Do something with lcsr */
end;
```

Comment: Note the code above this is NOT a compiled pl/sql procedure. It's an anonymous block that can be executed directly in SQLPLUS or a SQL Developer worksheet. It's basically a way of running pl/sql scripts directly without having to compile them.

Answer (score 0):

try this guys

BEGIN

Procedurename;

End

Answer (score 0):

If your stored procedure is in a package:

```
execute yourpackagename.yourstoredprocedure;
```